pybind11 virtual function overrides hang OpenMP loops when called from C++
I'm having a problem with pybind11 wrapped code using virtual function overrides in OpenMP sections of C++ code. An OpenMP loop will hang when run with more than one thread if there are calls to Python overrides in the body of the code. Since the macro PYBIND11_OVERRIDE acquires the GIL I thought these sorts of operations should be safe, but clearly I'm missing something.
Consider the following C++ code wrapped in pybind11:
#include "pybind11/pybind11.h"
#include "pybind11/functional.h"

namespace py = pybind11;
using namespace pybind11::literals;

#include <cstdio>

class A {
public:
  A()                               { printf("A::A()\n"); }    
  virtual ~A()                      { printf("A::~A()\n"); }   
  virtual void void_func() const    { printf("A::void_func()\n"); }
  virtual int int_func(int x) const { printf("A::int_func(%d)\n", x); return x + 1; }
};

void do_threaded_stuff(const A& a) {
  int sum = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for
  for (auto i = 0u; i < 10u; ++i) {
    a.void_func();
#pragma omp critical
    {
      sum = a.int_func(sum);
    }
  }
  printf("Final sum: %d\n", sum);
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Trampoline class for A
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class PYB11TrampolineA: public A {
public:
  using A::A;
  virtual void void_func() const override {
    PYBIND11_OVERRIDE(void, A, void_func);
  }
  virtual int int_func(int x) const override {
    PYBIND11_OVERRIDE(int, A, int_func, x);
  }
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Make the module
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PYBIND11_MODULE(virtual_override_thread, m) {
  py::class_<A, PYB11TrampolineA> obj(m, "A");
  obj.def(py::init<>());
  obj.def("void_func", (void (A::*)() const) &A::void_func);
  obj.def("int_func", (int (A::*)(int) const) &A::int_func);

  m.def("do_threaded_stuff", (void (*)(const A&)) &do_threaded_stuff, "a"_a);
}

If we exercise this code from Python (with more than one OpenMP thread) I see calls to do_threaded_stuff work fine with A objects (no Python overrides), but if I create a Python class inheriting from A and override these methods the loop in do_threaded_stuff will hang. Here is an example Python block that will reproduce the problem with the above Python module:
from virtual_override_thread import *

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)

    def void_func(self):
        print("B::void_func")

    def int_func(self, x):
        print("B::int_func({})".format(x))
        return x + 10

a = A()
do_threaded_stuff(a)    # OK

b = B()
do_threaded_stuff(b)    # Hang with OMP_NUM_THREADS > 1

How do I make these sorts of pybind11 overrides safe for threaded code in C++?

I had once a problem with python bindings and classic C++ threads (not omp though). Take a look at my post and see if guarding your m.def("do_threaded_stuff" with py::call_guard<py::gil_scoped_release>() ill do the job.

Just tried that, but sadly the hanging behavior persists.  This would be a difficult solution to implement in my actual code as well since I have hundreds of calls that usually do not have any Python overrides defined, but the user is able to optionally define Python classes with these overrides at any point.  This means I would essentially have to decorate all bindings that might ultimately call threaded code with this sort of guard, which turns into a maintenance mess.
